# get current date and time in groovy?

Tags: groovy, workflow, jenkins-pipeline, groovyshell

What is the code to get the current date and time in groovy? I've looked around and can't find an easy way to do this. Essentially I'm looking for linux equivalent of `date`

I have :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def call(){
    def date = new Date()
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
    return sdf.format(date)
}
```

but I need to print time as well.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`Date` has the time as well, just add `HH:mm:ss` to the date format:

```groovy
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
def date = new Date()
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
println sdf.format(date)
```

In case you are using JRE 8+ you can use `LocalDateTime`:

```groovy
import java.time.LocalDateTime
def dt = LocalDateTime.now()
println dt
```

Comment: I had to add `def` or `SimpleDateFormat` before `sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` using Java 12 in a Gradle build file.

Answer (score 26):

`Date` has the time part, so we only need to extract it from `Date`

**I personally** prefer the default `format` parameter of the `Date` when date and time needs to be separated instead of using the extra `SimpleDateFormat`

```
Date date = new Date()
String datePart = date.format("dd/MM/yyyy")
String timePart = date.format("HH:mm:ss")

println "datePart : " + datePart + "\ttimePart : " + timePart
```

Answer (score 10):

A oneliner to print timestamp of your local timezone:

```
String.format('%tF %<tH:%<tM', java.time.LocalDateTime.now())
```

Output for example: 2021-12-05 13:20

Comment: How do you add the seconds? I tried `'%tF %<tH:%<tM:%<tS'` and `'%tF %<tH:%<tM:%<ts'`

Answer (score 5):

Answering your question: `new Date().format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The most simple way, without any imports :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!groovy
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script{
                def date = new Date()
                sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
                println(sdf.format(date))
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```